# Can I make this work? Instantiating new arrays with class calls

Tags: java

I am trying to make my own class where one of the parameters is an array.

```
public class Node {
    int i;
    String title;
    int[] links;    

    Node(int i, String title, int[] links){
        this.i = i;
        this.title = title;
        this.links = links;
    }
}
```

Can I make this work? I want to call it by doing something like Node(4, "Title", [1,2,3])

Comment: You've already written all of the code, why don't you just add a main and test it?

Comment: I did, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to call it by doing something like Node(4, "Title", [1,2,3])

Well *that's* not going to work because `[1, 2, 3]` isn't a valid way of creating an array in Java, but you could certainly call it like this:

```
Node node = new Node(4, "Title", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Or you might want to use varargs:

```
Node(int i, String title, int... links)
```

which would allow you to call it as:

```
Node node = new Node(4, "Title", 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: varargs? What does that mean.

Comment: @YKQ56: Did you search before asking the question? A quick search for "varargs java" gave me the relevant documentation immediately.

Comment: Yeah I searched and those links are beyond my knowledge so to interpret your suggestion will take me hours.

Comment: It doesn't seem like varargs would be useful because how would I access all the variables?

Comment: varargs can be accessed like an array.

Comment: @YKQ56: "so to interpret your suggestion will take me hours." - With respect, that's called learning!

Comment: Yes I want to learn, but one thing at a time please. I am trying to learn some pretty simple stuff but I am getting lampooned with all these advanced and new additions to the language when I am just trying to learn the basics. I think I would prefer to avoid varargs for now, I am trying to make this as simple as possible so I can understand it.

Comment: Maybe this link could be useful to understand the varargs (since the explanation it's quite easy) http://www.javadb.com/using-varargs-in-java. Make sure that when you are using varargs always put the varargs at last!

Comment: @YKQ56: You specifically asked what varargs meant, and the links involved (particularly http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) would tell you that. I'm not sure how you expected me to be able to explain it in comments more effectively than a dedicated page would. (The link I've highlighted isn't even a particularly *long* page...)

Comment: @JonSkeet That is fine, thank you for the answer I just thought varargs was a misspelling of something. I will read up on those later once I learn about arraylists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.By creating anonymous array like this

```
   new  Node(4, "Title", new int[]{1,2,3});
```

Comment: This could work but I can't make it wokr like so       
                          public class graph1 {

                     public static void main (String[] args){
  ArrayList<Node> web = new ArrayList<Node>(); 
  web.add(0, (0, "google", new int[]{1,2}));
  
                      }
                               }